# How to make a count down in C++

Tags: c++

In python the `time.sleep()` is for count down time before execute next code:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
print("something")
```

So what is the equivalent to that in C++. Sorry for asking this simple question but I am new to C++

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "sleep_for" allows you to give the time you want to delay, and "sleep_until" allows you to delay until a exact time.
#include 
#include

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for, sleep_until
    using namespace std::chrono; // nanoseconds, system_clock, seconds

    sleep_for(nanoseconds(10));
    sleep_until(system_clock::now() + seconds(1));
}
```